# Calling java method with parameters in JSP file using OGNL

Tags: struts2, ognl

I am trying to display an image based on certain condition in JSP.

```xml
<s:if test="%{#employee.ratingInfo.ispromoted!=null && #employee.ratingInfo.ispromoted.code==56}">  
    <i class="check"></i>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <i class="invalid"></i>
</s:else>
```

I want to check if there is a way we can call a function in java by passing `employee.ratingInfo.ispromoted.code` as a parameter and then based on the return value we can display image. For example:

**JSP:**

```
<s:if test="checkRating(#employee.ratingInfo.ispromoted.code)">  
    <i class="check"></i>
</s:if>
<s:else>
      <i class="invalid"></i>
</s:else>
```

**Java:**

```
public boolean checkRating(int rating){
    if(rating==56){
        return true;
    }
      return false;
}
```

Is there a way we can achieve it, if I pass a parameter from a JSP to a method in Java to check if condition?

Comment: Just try it....

Answer (score 0):

Method call in OGNL is different than in Java. See [Calling Methods](https://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Calling_Methods) in OGNL language guide.

> OGNL calls methods a little differently from the way Java does,
> because OGNL is interpreted and must choose the right method at run
> time, with no extra type information aside from the actual arguments
> supplied. OGNL always chooses the most specific method it can find
> whose types match the supplied arguments; if there are two or more
> methods that are equally specific and match the given arguments, one
> of them will be chosen arbitrarily.
>
> In particular, a null argument matches all non-primitive types, and so
> is most likely to result in an unexpected method being called.

The value of `#employee.ratingInfo.ispromoted.code` should return primitive integer to match the parameter type of the method.